# Call Ajax Again in for loop

Tags: php, ajax, loops, for-loop

I want to request ajax many time in `for` loop . But it only return 1 value . **result.ID**. Can anyone help me?

```
  $('#show').html('');
  var min = parseInt($('#number_coupon_from').val());
  var max = parseInt($('#number_coupon_to').val());
  var total_time = parseInt($('#time_coupon').val())*1000;
  var randcoupon = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  var timetb = total_time/randcoupon;
  var random = 0;
  var i,j;
  for(i=0;i<randcoupon;i++)
  {
      for(j=random;j>=0;j--)
      {
        if(j==0)
        {
          $.ajax({
          url: 'backend/publish_auto/update',
          type: 'post',
          data: {},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (result) 
          {
            if(result.st)
            {
              $('#show').append('Update Coupon ID: '+result.ID+'<br />');
            }
          }
          });
        }
      }
  }
});
```

Thank you !!

Comment: That's not a great way to make use of Ajax

Comment: What do you try to achieve with this?

Comment: first check `randcoupon > 0` and what the purpose of inner loop?

Comment: @Manibharathi : randcoupon always > 0 . for loop ok but ajax request only 1 time . result return time = for loop but return one value

Comment: @user3631551 it works fine, check `result.st` value set in every ajax response.

Comment: Yes . For loop work fine . But ajax request only 1 time and result return once

Answer (score 0):

use `async:False` to get ajax response one by one

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'backend/publish_auto/update',
          async: false,
          type: 'post',
          data: {},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (result) 
          {
            if(result.st)
            {
              $('#show').append('Update Coupon ID: '+result.ID+'<br />');
            }
          }
          });
```

Comment: Thank you @user3176644 : But ajax response one time and die :( . A want it response many time :(